# Querying the sum for each value in column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the table with values as shown in below table:

[image: book table]

And I would like to get results as in below table:

[image: results]

I'm trying to query sum of ans1 like this for all rows

```
`SELECT sub_id, SUM(ans1) FROM booktable WHERE book_id =1 AND sub_id = 4 OR sub_id = 6`
```

But I'm not getting the expected result as shown in above table, instead I'm getting result for only one value in sub_id column. I'm a beginner in sql, please help. Thanks.

Comment: Sum is an aggregate function, this means you MUST use GROUP BY

Comment: thanks Hearner, GROUP BY helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT sub_id, SUM(ans1) FROM booktable
 WHERE book_id = 1 AND sub_id IN (4, 6)
Group by sub_id
```

Comment: you can remove `where` clause if you do not want it

Comment: thanks wajeeh, this helped. But I have around 70 values for `sub_id` and do not want to use `OR` for all of those in this query. So is there a way to do this without `OR` ?

Comment: But I have around 70 values for `sub_id` and do not want to use `OR` for all of those in this query. So is there a way to do this without `OR` to get the above result?

Comment: Thanks for `IN`, now listing all 70 values there would still make it long. Any other workaround other than this? thanks.

Comment: if you have a continues numbers then you can use `sub_id between 4 and 70` for example.

Comment: Both `IN` and `OR` clauses work and is fine for about 5 to 10 values. But I'm wondering is there any way to do this without adding all those 70 values of `sub_id` in the query.

Comment: yes, they are continuous but although first value starts with 4 last value ends with 102 and number of values are 70 in total. So will check whether `sub_id between 4 to 102` work or not.

Comment: Then you can use `Between first_num TO last_num`

Comment: But you must notice that: `Where book_id = 1 AND sub_id = 4 OR sub_id = 6` not equal to `Where book_id = 1 AND sub_id IN (4, 6)`, it must be `Where book_id = 1 AND (sub_id = 4 OR sub_id = 6)` be carful.